# O que significa o erro HTTP Error 403.14?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Bem, tenho uma Web Api, que configurada da seguinte forma:

`WebApiConfig.Cs`

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

e meu `GlobalAsax`

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Porém, por algum motivo não está encontrando os arquivos. E gera o seguinte problema:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
> O servidor Web está configurado para não listar o conteúdo deste diretório.
>
> Causas mais prováveis:
>
> Um documento padrão não está configurado para a URL solicitada, e a pesquisa no >diretório não está habilitada no servidor.

Porque isso acontece?

Como posso resolver este problema?

Comment: Qual versão do `IIS` você está utilizando? Dê uma olhada nesse [help da MS](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/942062/-http-error-403-14---forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage)

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade IIS 10.0 Express. Já havia tentado isso, sem resultados positivos

Comment: A rota que você está acessando não está servindo a sua api, simplesmente está tentando acessar um diretório e a visualização/lista de documentos não está habilitada. Qual é a url que você está tentando acessar?

Comment: > Para resolver:
> Botão direito no WebService > Set As Start Page Fonte: https://petshamarlow.blogspot.com/2013/06/erro-no-iis-80.html No meu caso tive que **clicar com o direito no projeto e escolher "Set as StartUp Project"**.

Answer (score -1):

Conforme o [help da MS](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/942062/-http-error-403-14---forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7-0-webpage):

> Porque isso acontece?

Esse problema ocorre porque o site não tem o recurso de Pesquisa no
Diretório habilitado, e o documento padrão não está configurado

> Como posso resolver este problema?

Abra um prompt de comando e, em seguida, vá para a pasta IIS Express
em seu computador. Por exemplo, vá para a seguinte pasta em um prompt
de comando:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express`
```

Digite o seguinte comando e pressione Enter:

```
appcmd set config /section:directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela atenção =), mas isso não resolveu o problema. Alguma outra forma?